# Q: Motor sizing for reeling application

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, torque

I would like to ask for some help.

My application is regulation of vertical speed of the camera, which is mounted on winding/unwinding reel. The camera follows the object (which moves vertically).

The load (weight) is constant, however due to the change in radius while winding, the torque changes.
To maintain desired vertical (linear) speed constant, the rotational velocity decreases while the torque increases and other way around when unwinding.

The rotational speed of the motor would have to be calculated since its a function of the current radius and desired linear(verical speed). The feedback for closed loop control of the linear velocity comes from the camera image.

The required torques (only load, without considering losses, frictions,..) are:
(for maximum desired linear vertical velocity of 2m/s)

0.165 Nm @ 2315 rpm

1.065 Nm @ 358 rpm

How do I choose the right motor size for this application? Would I need a gear? I'm searching for a BLDC motor.
Do I need to select a motor with the rated torque/speed of maximum speed and torque of my application (2315 rpm, 1.065Nm) ? ... that would be a huge motor :(

[image: Rotation speed vs Torque for different linear (vertical) speeds]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Separate the cable driving from the cable storage. Think how a mig welder delivers wire...

Comment: `The feedback for closed loop control of the linear velocity comes from the camera image.` then it doesn't really matter if you `control the power instead of the rotational speed`

Comment: @SolarMike that would work, but only for unwinding.

Comment: @Andyaka I agree, the statement was a bit confusing.

however I'm asking more about how to choose the proper motor for this application.

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is off-topic for this site unfortunately @Gnioco

Comment: Ok, so check out how film is wound between the bobbins on projection cameras.

Comment: What distance does the camera move through? Imagine a tape measure (thus giving you a mechansim to retract the tape), with the tape motion controlled by a pinch roller (like in a cassette player in play mode). Or just have the string in a continuous loop with a tensioner pulley.

Comment: @Andyaka...I'm not asking for any product recommendations - but for help how to choose motor for my application.

Comment: You've got a 10:1 torque ratio across your operating range - you really need to look at a different mechanical system - capstan drive, bigger drum, counterweight/springs. Otherwise, yes, you'll have to oversize your motor by about 10x.

Comment: @Jon thank you for the answer. My application is a reel which needs to store around 100m of line :/ How could I use capstan drive here?

Comment: The key to operating a motor efficiently is to run it fast at low torque. (Reasons easily found in other Q/As). So consider a 20000rpm motor (easy for BLDC) and 8:1 gearing. (Capstan drive is a good idea; the poor man's equivalent would be to increase the drum diameter until the torque ratio was only say 2:1)

Comment: @user_1818839 Thank you for your answer. What kind of gearing would you suggest? Can I use the timing belt for this speed?

Comment: Check the available timing belts and wheels. Do their speed and torque ratings meet your requirements?